# Testing a controller that execute a service with $resource response

Tags: angularjs, testing, jasmine, ngresource

I have a controller that use a service, resolve a promise and then set a variable.
I want to test if the variable has been set, How I do this?

Service.js

```
angular
.module('myModule')
.service('MyService',['$resource',function($resource){
  var r =  $resource('/users/:id',{id:'@id'});
  this.post = function(_user){
      return (new r(_user)).$save()
   }
}])
```

Controller

```
angular
.module('myModule')
.controller('myCtrl', ['MyService',function(MyService){
  var vm = this;
  vm.value = 0;
  vm.post = function(_user){

      MyService.post(_user).then(function(){
        vm.value = 1;
      });
  };


}])
```

controller_spec

```
describe('Test Controller',function(){
  beforeEach(module('myModule'));
  beforeEach(inject(function($controller, MyService){
    this.ctrl = $controller('myCtrl');
  }))

  it('after save value is 1',function(){
    this.ctrl.post({name: 'chuck'});

    //Always this.ctrl.value it's equal to 0
    expect(this.ctrl.value).toBeEqual(1);
  });

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

mock the service method and return a promise, then resolve it when you need it.

```
describe('Test Controller',function(){
  var postDefer;
  beforeEach(module('myModule'));
  beforeEach(inject(function($controller, MyService, $q){
    postDefer = $.defer();
    spyOn(MyService, 'post').and.returnValue(postDefer.promise);
    this.ctrl = $controller('myCtrl', {MyService : MyService});
  }))

  it('after save value is 1',function(){
    this.ctrl.post({name: 'chuck'});

    postDefer.resolve();

    scope.$apply();
    expect(this.ctrl.value).toBeEqual(1);
  });

});
```

Comment: why the `then`method it's executed and my value is updated when I use the scope.$apply() method?? It is because the function provided in the  `then` method are still waiting for `$digest` process ? I'll be very graceful if someone helps to me to understand this.

Comment: you need $scope.$apply() called, to tell AngularJS that an asynchronous event just occurred. In this case, you just resolved a promise.